# How can I center two columns in a row on this theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have this theme: https://www.similaricons.com/demos/milano/about.html, And I want to reduce the persons shown below the "Be Creative." block down to 2. Now, when I remove two persons, the remaining stick to the left side. I don't want that. Instead, I want them both to be in the center when I have an `lg` resolution. Can you help?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

#### What you could do is place the divs in single row in a table. Check out my example below:

```css
#tbl_container {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

#tbl_container > table {
  margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.pic_block {
  background: black;
  width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <div id="tbl_container">
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <div class="pic_block"></div>
                  <div class="pic_block"></div>
                  <div class="pic_block"></div>
                  <div class="pic_block"></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```